# Error when adding new column to data frame after grouped data process

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add 25th percentile information of the particular column `patient` after `groupby('score')` but getting error as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'patient': [242, 151, 111,122, 342],
        'obs': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
        'treatment': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'score': ['strong', 'weak', 'weak', 'weak', 'strong']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['patient', 'obs', 'treatment', 'score'])

df

   patient  obs  treatment   score
0      242    1          0  strong
1      151    2          1    weak
2      111    3          0    weak
3      122    1          1    weak
4      342    2          0  strong


quantile_25 = []
df_g=df.groupby("score")

for col in df.keys():
    if col=='patient':

        Q1 = df_g.apply(lambda _df: _df.np.percentile(_df[feature], q = 25))
        quantile_25.append(Q1)

    else:
        pass

df['std_dev_patient'] = df.score.map(quantile_25[0])
```

> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of >'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

I would like to keep the same `for loop` as I would like to add other stats as new column.

thx

the expected output

```
   patient  obs  treatment   score   quantile_25
0      242    1          0  strong     ..
1      151    2          1    weak     ..
2      111    3          0    weak     ..
3      122    1          1    weak     ..
4      342    2          0  strong     ..
```

Comment: this line `_df.np.percentile(_df[feature], q = 25)` for me is not compiling, saying that DataFrame do not have a np attribute, isn't it `np.percentile(_df[feature], q = 25)`? Also what is `feature` ?

Comment: `try:
    df['new_col']=df.groupby('score')['patient'].transform(lambda x: np.percentile(x,25))
except KeyError:
    pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution without using apply:

```
df_g=df.groupby("score")
for col in df.columns:
    if col=='patient':
        df['std_dev_patient'] = df_g[col].transform(lambda group: np.percentile(group, q=25))
    else:
        pass
```

Output:

```
   patient  obs  treatment   score  std_dev_patient
0      242    1          0  strong            267.0
1      151    2          1    weak            116.5
2      111    3          0    weak            116.5
3      122    1          1    weak            116.5
4      342    2          0  strong            267.0
```